# Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale- temperature vs Years

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
    ggplot(data = tempdata, aes(x = Year)) +
    +   geom_line(aes(y = Dec, colour = "Dec")) +
    +   scale_colour_manual("", 
    +                       breaks = c("Dec"),
    +                       values = c("Dec"="red")) +
    +   xlab("Year") +
    +   scale_y_continuous("Temperatura (C)", limits = c(-80,100)) + 
    +   labs(title="Temperature variation since 1880")
```

> Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale

Here is [a link to the data file](https://data.giss.nasa.gov/gistemp/tabledata_v3/GLB.Ts.csv). The processed data file that I have the value multiplied by 100.

Comment: I was not able to add the link for the data file for some reason. Here is the link https://data.giss.nasa.gov/gistemp/tabledata_v3/GLB.Ts.csv

Comment: The problem is that ggplot thinks `Dec` is categorical (discrete) rather than numeric. The last row of the `Dec` column has the character string `"***"`, signifying missing data. When you read in the data (with, say, `read.csv`) R is treating the column as character instead of numeric. The code below will treat `"***"` as missing data when the data file is loaded into R and the resulting `Dec` column will be numeric: `tempdata = read.csv("GLB.Ts.csv", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, na.strings="***")`.

Comment: Also, if you just want the set the line to a specific color, do `geom_line(aes(y = Dec), colour="red")` and get rid of the `scale_colour_manual` statement.

Comment: Thank you epipi10! That worked, the problem was the "****'". I assumed that it will automatically drop that data. I started programming in R recently so not well versed with the language just yet. Appreciate your help!

Comment: By default, `read.csv` only treats `"NA"` and empty cells as representing a missing value in numeric data (you can see this is in the help for `read.csv` by typing `?read.csv` and looking at the `na.strings` argument in the `read.table` function and the description of the `na.strings` argument further down). If there are other strings in the data (like "***") `read.csv` will assume the column is character, rather than numeric unless you use the `na.strings` argument to tell the function which strings to treat as missing values.